# PHP POST using JS Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I don't know why it's not working. It returns empty `$_POST`.

JS:

```
const updateRequest = new FormData();
updateRequest.append('updateRequest', 'next-period');


fetch('file.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  data: updateRequest
})

  .then((response) => response.text())

  .then((text) => {
    console.log(text);
  })
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  var_dump(empty($_POST));

}
```

In the PHP file, the server request is POST but var_dump logs true.

Comment: Do a console.log(updateRequest) to see what's in there. Maybe you're not really sending anything.

Comment: @Difster if I use formData.values() it returns the correct values.

Comment: what does simply `var_dump($_POST);` log?

Comment: @ADyson it logs bool(true).

Comment: No, that'd be the output of `var_dump(empty($_POST));`. I asked about the output of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I've voting to close this as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. You put the request body in a property called `data` when it is named `body` in the Fetch API.

Comment: @ADyson response is null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), if you want to send data to the server in the request body (as you would for a POST) then you put it in the `body` option. There is no `data` option available. If you provide that to the Fetch method it is not expecting it and will simply ignore it. Perhaps you've confused it with the syntax for jQuery $.ajax() (which does have a `data` option) or something?

You need to write:

```
fetch('file.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: updateRequest //"body" instead of "data"
})
```

Demo (watch the network tab when running the fiddle to see the data included in the body): http://jsfiddle.net/2vx0rp3q/

Comment: yes, i get confused with Ajax. Sorry for that and thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change data in body

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('login-form'));
fetch("/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
});
```

as defined here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch